# Will I get a passport stamp if I go to Ireland from Germany on a U.S passport?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, ireland, passport-stamps

Due to extenuating circumstances, I'm running out of time to get my residence visa in Germany (I'm a graduate student in Berlin) -- I've been told that I need to leave the Schengen area for a week or so to extend the time that my university can get my visa application into the foreigners office...

I've also been told that I will need a passport stamp to show that I was out of the Schengen countries for x amount of time.

Would I get a passport stamp for entering or exiting Ireland or the UK/Scotland if I'm coming from Germany? I have a U.S passport.

Please let me know if you know...I'm in such a bind...

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this plan will work? Because you're still up against the 90/180 clock regardless of whether you exit and reenter again. Visa runs do not work for Schengen zones like Germany

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen leaving for a week won't reset the clock, but it will pause it.

Comment: @phoog That is correct however my point is unless the approval is going to happen within one week, then the trip will serve no purpose.

Comment: Well, with the holidays coming up, the foreigners office has a lot of closures and I have basically one day to try to get a walk-in appt (which I'm going to try next Thursday) -- I was advised that if this doesn't work, my only other option is to leave for a week and return, so my university can get my visa app in when they reopen on Jan. 8th (my 90 days are up on Jan 5th...)

Comment: I don't see why the passport stamp from Ireland should matter - you will get a stamp when you leave the Schengen region, and another when you return.  That will be the proof that you were out of Schengen/Germany, not the stamps from Ireland.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a US passport (like any non-EU/EEA passport) will be stamped when you enter Ireland or the UK. There will be no exit stamp when you leave; Ireland and the UK do not have exit controls. But even if your destination didn't give you an entry stamp (as if you returned to the US, potentially), the Schengen exit stamp is really what they'll be looking for, and you'll get that regardless of where you go to.

Incidentally, prepare for a bit of grilling when you enter Ireland or the UK. "I'm here to get around immigration restrictions, but I promise I'll leave in a week" is not exactly what an IO wants to hear. Bring documentation of everything, particularly documenting the absolute certainty that you're about to be issued a resident visa.

Comment: In other words, the answer is "you won't get *a* passport stamp, you'll get two!"

Answer (score 2):

Going to Ireland will look exactly like what this is: a [visa run](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_visa#Visa_run).

There are some LCCs (Wow, for example) with extremely cheap fares back to the USA. You may want to consider going back home for even a week as it’ll give the clearest indication you have a place in your home country to go back to.

Comment: @FreeMan thx. Guess redirect links don’t work between se and wiki. Linked to the redirected section.

Comment: No worries, works now!

Comment: Under the 90/180 rule, it doesn't matter whether one goes to Ireland or the USA.  Why would it help to go to the USA?  Neither trip will reset the 90/180 clock, and both trips will pause it.

Comment: @phoog The OP is a US citizen, thus he cannot be refused entry to the US.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ireland is not very likely to refuse entry in this case.  The most restrictive thing they're likely to do is verify sufficient funds to buy a ticket to the US if necessary.  If the traveler describes the purpose of the trip by describing her plans during the week, it seems unlikely that the officer will think to ask why.  The German visa situation might not even come up.